# Unable to create authentication on shiny server pro

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am using shiny server pro to host my shiny application and want to create authentication  for user to access it.

As I am hosting multiple applications on server and did not have conf file in the folder of application for which I want to create authentication.
So I copied conf file from default folder which we get on shiny server and pasted in this app folder and replaced the references.

I ran below code to create the user name and getting following error.

```
# sudo /opt/shiny-server/bin/sspasswd /etc/shiny-server/myproject/passwd admin
```

Error: Password file does not exist; use -c to create it.

Can you please suggest how can I create the password file in order to create user names and have authentication completed.

Also, below is the code in my conf file after editing the folder name. Let me know if any changes are required in this also.

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Specify the authentication method to be used.
# Initially, a flat-file database stored at the path below.
auth_passwd_file /etc/shiny-server/nashboard/passwd;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location /nashboard {

    # Only up tp 20 connections per Shiny process and at most 3 Shiny processes
    # per application. Proactively spawn a new process when our processes reach
    # 90% capacity.
    utilization_scheduler 20 .9 3;

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server/nashboard;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
    app_init_timeout 250 ;
  }
}

# Provide the admin interface on port 4151
admin 4151 {

  # Restrict the admin interface to the usernames listed here. Currently
  # just one user named "admin"
  required_user admin;
}
~
~
~
```

Comment: Did you try ``use -c to create it`` ?

Comment: @netle - What is the exact command I need to use, when I try to use -c only, I get command not found error

Comment: i.e., ``sudo /opt/shiny-server/bin/sspasswd /etc/shiny-server/myproject/passwd admin -c`` ?

Comment: See more [here in the docs](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#sspasswd)

Comment: @Nutle Command used -
 sudo /opt/shiny-server/bin/sspasswd /etc/shiny-server/myproject/passwd admin -c
Error: Could not open file; use -c to create it.

Comment: what about ``sudo /opt/shiny-server/bin/sspasswd -c /etc/shiny-server/myproject/passwd admin`` ?

Comment: @Nutle Is it always "/etc/"? I used /srv/shiny-server/myproject/passwd admin -c and it went through and asked for the password. But when I am trying to access the application, it isn't asking for a password. is it the right way to do?

Comment: Not necessarily, I just used the location you used in the question :) About the last question: did you restart the server after setting the password? Are you using the "Pro" version?

Comment: @Nutle I changed the location in both. while creating the password and in config also. Hope that is correct. I am using shiny server pro and did not start the server after setting up the password. Do we need to? If yes, how do we do it?

Comment: Did you try [going through the documentation?](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#require-user-authentication-on-an-application)

Comment: @Nutle Yes, I have the users created according to documentation only. The only difference is I replaced etc with srv in path because that is path of my aplication. But application is running without asking for any authentication.

Comment: @Nutle Did restart the server also, but not working